# Vaadin Combobox and LazyInitializationException

Tags: vaadin

My question maybe simple simple but I don't understand why Vaadin combobox tries to get a colletion of nested entities set in a combobox if I do not call these items of collection.

See this:

```
@Entity
public class Estado extends AbstractEntity {
    
    private String nome;
    private String sigla;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "estado")
    private List<Municipio> municipios;
    
    
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getSigla() {
        return sigla;
    }
    public void setSigla(String sigla) {
        this.sigla = sigla;
    }
    public List<Municipio> getMunicipios() {
        return municipios;
    }
    public void setMunicipios(List<Municipio> municipios) {
        this.municipios = municipios;
    }

private void initCbEstados() {
    
    if (cbEstados.isEmpty()) {
        List<Estado> estados = estadoService.findAllEager();
        cbEstados.setItems(estados);
    }

    cbEstados.addValueChangeListener(e -> updateCbMunicipios());

    cbEstados.setClearButtonVisible(true);

    cbEstados.setItemLabelGenerator(Estado::getNome);

    cbEstados.setWidth("50%");
    
}

private void updateViewToEdit(){
    
    if (isEditMode) {
        
        Estado estado = entity.getEndereco().getEstado();
        
    ***//this throws LazyInitializationException***
        cbEstados.setValue(estado);
        
        updateCbMunicipios();
    }
```

I do not call at any time estado.getMunicipios. But apparently the behavior of the combobox tries to infer in the municipios released the exception.

Is this expected behavior?

I don't think it should be?

Comment: In `updateViewToEdit()`. Where does the `entity` come from? Seems you are not running inside a transaction. Assuming you are running Spring Boot with Spring Data JPA. I followed [Thorben Janssens tips](https://thorben-janssen.com/lazyinitializationexception) and configured `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false`. I also have `@Transactional` on my service methods. So that would be `findAllEager()` in your case.

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace and show wht finalAllEager is doing?

Comment: Thanks Simon i have had solved my selve.

Answer (score 0):

Sory, fisrt post on stack overflow and i was not familiar with the platform and ended not posting the entire code. The error occurred in

**cbEstados.addValueChangeListener(e -> updateCbMunicipios());**

that during the debug was not visible because it was occurring within the vaadin classes. The problem was solved by searching for the municpios in **updateCbMunicpios();**  So when **FormBase** calls   **beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent event)** the **readBean()** set values on **cbEstados** that fires **ValuechangeListener** and load the ***LazeInicializaTionExceptions*** because Entity comes from the Request Scoope and not Fully filed to set the Value of Municipio in **cbMunicipios**. And cbMunicipios would be empty firing anhoter error from Vaadin.

```
public class FornecedorForm extends CadastroFormBaseGenerics<Fornecedor, FornecedorService> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5599427454458715210L;

    EstadoService estadoService;

    @PropertyId("ativo")
    private Checkbox ckAtivo;

    @PropertyId("razaoSocial")
    private TextField txtRazaoSocial;

    @PropertyId("nomeFantasia")
    private TextField txtNomeFantasia;

    @PropertyId("cnpj")
    private TextField txtCnpj;

    @PropertyId("contato")
    private TextField txtContato;

    @PropertyId("telefoneContato")
    private TextField txtTelContato;

    @PropertyId("telefone")
    private TextField txtTelefone;

    @PropertyId("observacao")
    TextArea txtObservacao;

    private ComboBox<Estado> cbEstados;

    private ComboBox<Municipio> cbMunicipios;

    private TextField txtCep;

    private TextField txtLogradouro;

    private TextField txtNumero;

    private TextField txtComplemento;

    @PropertyId("emailContato")
    EmailField txtEmailContato;

    private FormLayout layout;

    HorizontalLayout layoutEstado;

    public FornecedorForm(@Autowired EstadoService estadoService) {
        super(Fornecedor.class, "Fornecedor");
        this.estadoService = estadoService;

        updateViewToEdit();

    }

    protected void configureAdditionalBinds() {

        getBinder().bind(cbEstados, "endereco.estado");
        getBinder().bind(cbMunicipios, "endereco.municipio");
        getBinder().bind(txtCep, "endereco.cep");
        getBinder().bind(txtLogradouro, "endereco.logradouro");
        getBinder().bind(txtNumero, "endereco.numero");
        getBinder().bind(txtComplemento, "endereco.complemento");

    }

    private void initCbEstados() {

        cbEstados = new ComboBox<Estado>("Estado");

        List<Estado> estados = estadoService.findAllEager();
        cbEstados.setItems(estados);

        cbEstados.addValueChangeListener(e -> updateCbMunicipios());

        cbEstados.setClearButtonVisible(true);

        cbEstados.setItemLabelGenerator(Estado::getNome);

        cbEstados.setWidth("50%");

    }

    private void initCbMunicpios() {

        cbMunicipios = new ComboBox<Municipio>("Município");
        cbMunicipios.setItemLabelGenerator(Municipio::getNome);
        cbMunicipios.setWidth("50%");
        cbMunicipios.setReadOnly(true);

    }

    private void updateCbMunicipios() {

        if (cbEstados.getValue() != null) {

            cbMunicipios.clear();

            cbMunicipios.setReadOnly(false);

            Estado estado = estadoService.findMunicipios(cbEstados.getValue());

            cbMunicipios.setItems(estado.getMunicipios());

        } else {
            cbMunicipios.clear();
            cbMunicipios.setReadOnly(true);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void initViewComponents() {

        layoutEstado = new HorizontalLayout();

        layout = new FormLayout();

        layoutEstado.setSizeFull();

        initCbEstados();
        initCbMunicpios();

        ckAtivo = new Checkbox("Ativo ?", true);
        txtRazaoSocial = new TextField("Razão Social");
        txtNomeFantasia = new TextField("Nome Fantasia");
        txtCnpj = new TextField("CNPJ");
        txtCnpj.setWidth("25%");
        // txtCnpj.setErrorMessage("CNPJ Incorreto.");
        // txtCnpj.setPattern("^[0-9]{2}?[-s.]?[0-9]{3}[-s.]?[0-9]{3}[-s/]?[0-9]{4}[-s-]?[0-9]{2}$");

        txtTelefone = new TextField("Telefone");

        txtContato = new TextField("Nome Contato");

        txtTelContato = new TextField("Telefone Contato");

        txtEmailContato = new EmailField("Email Contato");
        txtEmailContato.setClearButtonVisible(true);
        txtEmailContato.setErrorMessage("Formato do E-mail incorreto");
        txtEmailContato.setRequiredIndicatorVisible(false);

        txtLogradouro = new TextField("Logradouro");

        txtNumero = new TextField("Número");
        txtNumero.setWidth("50px");

        txtCep = new TextField("CEP");
        txtCep.setPattern("^[0-9]{5}?[-s-]?[0-9]{3}$");
        txtCep.setPlaceholder("00000-000");
        txtCep.setRequired(true);
        txtCep.setErrorMessage("Informe o CEP");

        txtCep.setWidth("75px");

        txtComplemento = new TextField("Complemento");

        txtObservacao = new TextArea("Observações");

        layout.add(ckAtivo, 2);
        layout.add(txtCnpj, 2);
        layout.add(txtRazaoSocial, txtNomeFantasia);

        layout.add(layoutEstado, 2);

        layout.add(txtLogradouro, txtNumero);
        layout.add(txtComplemento, txtCep, txtTelefone);

        HorizontalLayout layoutContato = new HorizontalLayout(txtContato, txtTelContato, txtEmailContato);
        layoutContato.setSizeFull();
        txtContato.setWidth("40%");
        txtEmailContato.setWidth("40%");
        txtTelContato.setWidth("20%");

        layout.add(layoutContato, 2);

        layout.add(txtObservacao, 2);

        super.formLayout.add(layout);

        layoutEstado.add(cbEstados, cbMunicipios);

        configureAdditionalBinds();

    }

    protected void updateViewToEdit() {

        if (isEditMode) {

            Estado estado = entity.getEndereco().getEstado();
            estado = estadoService.findMunicipios(estado);

            cbEstados.setValue(estado);

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void getNewEntityToPersist() {

        entity = new Fornecedor();
        entity.setEndereco(new Endereco());
        ckAtivo.setValue(true);

    }

}

public abstract class CadastroFormBaseGenerics<T, SERVICE extends ServiceInterface<T>> extends FormLayout
        implements BeforeEnterObserver {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7069232922824142288L;

    protected T entity;
    @Autowired
    private SERVICE service;

    private final Class<T> beanClass;

    private Binder<T> binder;

    private String nomeDoBean;
    protected boolean isEditMode;

    private Button btnSave = new Button("Salvar");
    private Button btnDelete = new Button("Excluir");
    private Button btnCancel = new Button("Cancelar");

    protected VerticalLayout formLayout = new VerticalLayout();;

    private HorizontalLayout buttonsLayout = new HorizontalLayout();

    public CadastroFormBaseGenerics(Class<T> beanClass, String nomeDoBean) {

        this.beanClass = beanClass;

        this.nomeDoBean = nomeDoBean;

    }

    protected abstract void initViewComponents();

    @PostConstruct
    private void inicialize() {

        checkEditMode();

        initBinder();

        initViewComponents();

        addComponentAsFirst(formLayout);

        configureFormLayout();

        getEntityToEdit();

        updateViewToEdit();

    }

    protected abstract void updateViewToEdit();

    protected void initBinder() {

        binder = new BeanValidationBinder<T>(beanClass);

    }

    protected void setPlaceHolders(String beanName) {

        String primeiraLetra = "" + beanName.charAt(0);

        primeiraLetra = primeiraLetra.toUpperCase();
        char letraMaiuscula = primeiraLetra.charAt(0);

        char[] cArray = beanName.toCharArray();

        cArray[0] = letraMaiuscula;

        beanName = new String(cArray);

        for (int i = 0; i < formLayout.getComponentCount(); i++) {

            Component c = formLayout.getComponentAt(i);

            if (c.getClass().getName().equals("com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.TextField")) {

                TextField aux = (TextField) c;
                aux.setPlaceholder(aux.getLabel() + " " + beanName + "...");
                aux.setClearButtonVisible(true);

            }

        }
    }

    protected void configureFormLayout() {

        formLayout.setSizeFull();

        // formLayout.setMargin(true);
        formLayout.setSpacing(true);
        formLayout.setPadding(true);
        formLayout.setAlignItems(Alignment.AUTO);
        formLayout.setMargin(true);
        // add(formLayout, 2);

        configureButtonsLayout();

    }

    void configureButtonsLayout() {

        btnDelete.setVisible(false);

        btnSave.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);
        btnDelete.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_ERROR);

        buttonsLayout = new HorizontalLayout();

        buttonsLayout.add(btnSave, btnDelete, btnCancel);
        buttonsLayout.setMargin(true);

        buttonsLayout.setPadding(true);
        buttonsLayout.setSizeFull();

        configureButtonEvents();

        add(buttonsLayout, 2);

    }

    private void configureButtonEvents() {

        btnSave.addClickListener(saveEvent -> save());
        btnDelete.addClickListener(deleteEvent -> delete());
        btnCancel.addClickListener(cancelEvent -> clearForm());

    }

    private void save() {

        String msg = nomeDoBean + " Alterada(o) com sucesso.";

        if (!isEditMode) {

            msg = nomeDoBean + " Cadastrada(o) com sucesso.";
            getNewEntityToPersist();

            // getNewEntity();

        }

        try {
            getBinder().writeBean(entity);
            service.save(entity);
            clearForm();
            showSucess(msg);

        } catch (DoisCsCrudException e) {

            showWarnig(nomeDoBean + " já cadastrado. Verique.");
            logException(e, "Metodo save()");

        } catch (ValidationException e) {

            showWarnig("Verique os campos obrigatórios.");

        }

    }

    /**
     * {@summary} Você deve implementar o {@code} entity = New POJO este método é
     * chamado toda vez que {@code} save() para criar um novo BEAN a ser persistido.
     */
    protected abstract void getNewEntityToPersist();

    private void delete() {
        try {

            service.delete(entity);
            clearForm();
            showSucess(nomeDoBean + " removida(o) com sucesso.");

        } catch (DoisCsCrudException e) {
            showWarnig(nomeDoBean + " não pode ser removida(o), pois existem registros que dependem dele. %/n "
                    + "Inative-o para que não seja mais exibido.");
        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void getEntityToEdit() throws ClassCastException {

        if (isEditMode) {

            btnDelete.setVisible(true);
            this.entity = (T) VaadinServletRequest.getCurrent().getAttribute("entityToEdit");

        }

    }

    private boolean checkEditMode() {

        if (VaadinServletRequest.getCurrent().getAttribute("entityToEdit") != null) {

            isEditMode = true;
        } else {
            isEditMode = false;
        }

        return isEditMode;

    }

    /**
     * Sempre deve ser chamado após um click no botão salvar, cancelar ou excluir
     */
    protected void clearForm() {

        // Desabilita o botão para excluir um Bean Cadastrado
        btnDelete.setVisible(false);

        // Seta editmode para falso, garantido que a proxima interação
        // seja com um bean novo
        isEditMode = false;

        clearBinder();

    }

    protected void clearBinder() {

        binder.readBean(null);

    }

    protected void showSucess(String message) {

        createNotification(message, NotificationVariant.LUMO_SUCCESS, 3000);

    }

    protected void showError(String message) {

        createNotification(message, NotificationVariant.LUMO_ERROR, 5000);

    }

    protected void showWarnig(String message) {
        createNotification(message, NotificationVariant.LUMO_CONTRAST, 10000);

    }

    private void createNotification(String message, NotificationVariant variant, int duration) {

        Notification n = new Notification(message);
        n.setDuration(7000);
        n.addThemeVariants(variant);
        n.setPosition(Position.TOP_CENTER);

        n.open();

    }

    protected void logException(Exception e, String logDesc) {

        System.out.println("################  " + logDesc.toUpperCase() + " $$ " + getClass().getSimpleName()
                + "  ################");

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    public Binder<T> getBinder() {
        return binder;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent event) {

        binder.bindInstanceFields(this);
        if (entity != null) {

            getBinder().readBean(entity);

        }

    }

}
```